# Nodejs not able to connect to mongodb on cloud shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, microservices

My MongoDB server is hosted on google-cloud VM. I wish to create App Engine microservice. to test connectivity,

my server.js looks like

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const test = require('assert');
// Connection url
const url = 'mongodb://testmongodb:27017';
// Database Name
const dbName = 'test';
// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true },function(err, client) {
if(err){console.log(err)}
else {console.log("Connected successfully")}
});
```

it works perfectly if i connect via another vm. But does not work when trying to execute (npm start) the same code via **Google Cloud Shell**. I get the error

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [testmongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testmongodb testmongodb:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/google/mng/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:562:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/google/mng/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:316:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/google/mng/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [testmongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testmongodb testmongodb:27017]',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

i get exactly the same error when deployed the service [gcloud app deploy]

please help.

Comment: on mongod.conf, changed the setting of bindip to 0.0.0.0

Comment: firewall setting changed to open port 27017

Comment: Please help me understand, what is "testmongodb" ? Is it the name of the vm in the virtual network ?

Comment: yes, its the hostname of VM on which my mongodb resides. 
Its in the same virtual network

Comment: Cool. I guess using localhost instead of the hostnname should work if both servers are in the same VM.

Comment: point here is, it will not work, when i deploy it to GAE(App Engine). 
And thats what I want to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried following [this official quickstart for App Engine to MongoDB](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/mongodb)? Disregard the nconf/MongoLab part, as you have MongoDB running in a GCP instance. Also, check if the port is open in that same instance.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine Standard does support connecting to a MongoDB instance with the very same library that you were using.  [This example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/mongodb) works for Standard and Flexible as well.

The issue is with how you were connecting. You have to create the URI like this:

```
let uri = `mongodb://${user}:${pass}@${host}:${port}`;
```

Where as, in your code, you have this:

```
const url = 'mongodb://testmongodb:27017';
```

You are missing the user and password in your URI (assuming that `testmongodb` is your hostname).

Comment: I tried that as well  user created via db.createuser()
it did not work  

then I played around app.yaml from changing standard to flex and back from flex to standard. 

it worked only when flex was not mentioned. 

may be I am doing something wrong. Can I pm you.

Comment: If you don't specify environment in your app.yaml file, it defaults to standard environment. So, you are saying 'it worked only when flex was not mentioned', so it's indeed working in Standard.

Answer (score -1):

When connecting to a server on the same machine, use mongodb://localhost:27017.

Comment: yes, with the same machine it will work (and it works). 
the point is that when I deploy the service in google App Engine. It will not work. 

Therefore it has to have a qualified hostname

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your support and answers.

seems the change I needed to do in my `app.yaml` file.
`env: standard` does not support **mongodb**. you will have to use 
    `env: flex` in your **yaml** file which will be used by `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`  command

Comment: This is not correct, as MongoDB is supported in Standard with the very same library you were using. Check my answer.