# How can I deploy a Flask website with MongoDB to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm using Flask as my backend and MongoDB for storing the data. I've connected my Website to MongoDB Atlas and tested everything locally and it works as expected. But when I try deploying the website to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) MongoDB doesn't work at all. The only configuration file that I have is app.yaml and it looks like this:

```
    runtime: python
    env: flex
    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

    runtime_config:
      python_version: 3

    handlers:
    - url: /static
      static_dir: static
    - url: /.*
     script: auto
```

I have connected my project to an Instance and enabled API Engine. For deployment, I simply ran the following command in Cloud Shell

```
    gcloud app deploy
```

Do I need any other configuration files to run MongoDB? Or is the whole process wrong and I need to do it in another way.

Comment: You will have to pay to google. Otherwise you will have to use sql server crack and merge with M

Comment: I'm using the free trial. They give you 300$ for a year so I don't think there's a problem with that

Comment: How do you reach your MongoDB cluster? What are the network permissions/config on your MongoDB atlas console?

Comment: I've set the Network connection to connect from everywhere 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: What do you mean by `I have connected my project to an Instance`?

Comment: By following https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Comment: Do you mean that you see your app engine flex into the compute engine list?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: There is a special trick to do for seeing it? AFAIK, I never view the App Engine Flex instance in the compute instance list.

Comment: Are you getting any error when trying to connect to Mongo, or what is the issue you are facing right now? Also, It may be worth that you check either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946930/connect-to-mongodb-atlas-from-google-app-engine) or [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app) in order to get a better grasp on how to connect App Engine to MongoDB Atlas